# How to test alias import

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

If I have something like:

`import { buildPath as buildSRPPath } from '@/router/srp-routes';`

Do I mock it Like:

```
jest.mock('@/router/srp-routes', () => ({
  buildPath: jest.fn()
}));
```

Or do I need `buildSRPPath`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jest.mock](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestmockmodulename-factory-options) replaces the module with a mock so the mock should contain what the module exports.

Example:

```
// ---- lib.js ----
export const func = () => {
  return 'func called';
}



// ---- code.js ----
import { func as somethingElse } from './lib';

export const useFunc = () => {
  return somethingElse();
}



// ---- code.test.js ----
import { useFunc } from './code';

jest.mock('./lib', () => ({
  func: () => 'mocked func'  // mock 'func' since that is what lib exports
}));

test('useFunc', () => {
  expect(useFunc()).toBe('mocked func');  // PASSES
});
```

So in your case you are correct to use `buildPath`.

Comment: Thanks @brian-lives-outdoors. One question, You have the export in code.js. How my code looks is that actually there is an import inside code.js. so it's like `import { buildPath as buildSRPPath } from '@/router/srp-routes';` .

Comment: When you mock the module using jest.mock you just need to make sure you mock what the module exports.  The module itself gets modified by jest.mock so any code that imports it will import the modified module and the aliases will automatically refer to the mock.

Comment: @MikeTaatgen I updated my example code to demonstrate testing code that imports using an alias from the module to be mocked, let me know if that helps.